# PHP Insert SQL en web Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, paypal

Tengo una función PHP que debería ejecutarse en los Hooks de un plugin que recoge mensajes de Paypal. Esta función sólo debe insertar ciertas partes de esos mensajes (nombre del cliente, dirección, mail, etc) en una tabla de la base de datos, pero por mucho que pruebo, no inserta nada.

Esta es la función:

```
function registrar_pago($posted) {
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'T_MOVIMIENTOS';

    $mc_gross = isset($posted["mc_gross"]) ? $posted["mc_gross"] : '';
    $payer_email = isset($posted["payer_email"]) ? $posted["payer_email"] : '';
    $txn_type = isset($posted["txn_type"]) ? $posted["txn_type"] : '';


    $data=array(
        'EMAIL' => $payer_email, 
        'MOVIMIENTO' => $txn_type,
        'CANTIDAD' => $mc_gross,  
        'FECHA' => date('d/m/y') );


    $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);

}


 add_action("paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_ipn_response_handler", "registrar_pago", 10, 1);
```

El plugin por su lado está recogiendo bien todos los datos de los mensajes, por lo que descarto que el problema esté ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que esta todo bien en la consulta con:

```
echo "El error es: " . $wpdb->last_error;
```

Esto puede darte alguna pista o detectar algún problema con la consulta y el proceso del insert.

---

También podría ser por el parámetro de los formatos:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
'table', 
array( 
    'column1' => 'value1', 
    'column2' => 123 
), 
array( 
    '%s', 
    '%d' 
)
```

);

Mira de meterle el formato...

```
 <?php $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row